# 802.11s mesh network cannot ping between different Ubuntu systems

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, 802.11

I am setting up an 802.11s mesh network on Ubuntu Linux systems, after disabling NetworkManager and netplan.io. The following commands are an example of what is used to set up the mesh on one particular system (with a particular IP address). Each system has a different hard coded IP from the 192.168.101.x range.

```
#!/bin/bash
rfkill unblock wlan

iw reg set US
iw dev wlan1 interface add mesh0 type mesh
ip addr add 192.168.101.200/24 dev mesh0
iw dev mesh0 set meshid mymesh
iw dev mesh0 set channel 6
ip link set dev mesh0 up
```

I have two different kinds of systems:

Type A system is an Intel NUC7i7DNBE installed with Ubuntu 16.04 Kernel: 4.15.0-43-generic #46~16.04.1-Ubuntu

Type B system is an Intel NUC8i7HV installed with Ubuntu 18.04 Kernel: 4.20.0-042000-generic #201812232030

The problem is that only Type A systems can ping each other and Type B systems can ping each other, Type A and Type B cannot ping each other, responding with a "no route to host" error. I have experimented connecting to the mesh using laptops and Raspberry Pi systems. Any of these systems (Type A, Type B, laptop, RPi) can only ping either Type A or Type B systems, never both types. Some laptops can ping Type A and other laptops can ping Type B, for example.

What could be causing the diffrences in these systems and preventing them from being able to ping or send data to each other? I have tried various kernel versions and both Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 and have not yet found a clear pattern of what types of systems work with which. It seems to be related to the hardware rather than the operating system or kernel version installed.

The network adapter being used on all systems is an ASUS USB-N13 N300 USB 2.0 Wifi Adapter.

Comment: So, are you hard-coding IP addresses for all the devices?  Are they all different?  Are they all in the same logical network?  … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.